# Invoke onNext in different threads (RxJava Android)

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I receive an object (city) and want to dispatch this data in different threads (reflect on mobile screen and save to DB this city). This is my code:

```
    private CompositeSubscription subscriptions;
    ...
        @Override
            public void onAddButtonClick(String cityName) {
                Observable<City> obs = repository.getCity(cityName);
                if (obs != null){
                    Subscription subscription = obs
                            .subscribeOn(backgroundThread)
                            .observeOn(mainThread)
                            .subscribe(
                                    city -> {
                                        view.cityExists();
                                        repository.saveCityToDb(city);
                                    }

                            );

                    subscriptions.add(subscription);    
                } else {
                    view.showCouldNotFindCity();
                }    
            }

    @Override
    public void subscribe() {
        subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    }

    @Override
    public void unsubscribe() {
        subscriptions.clear();
    }
```

So this method `view.cityExists();` I want to run on UI thread and `repository.saveCityToDb(city);` on the background thread. How can I do it?

The method `getCity(...);` returns `Observable<City>`:

```
public Observable<City> getCity(String name){
        return fileRepository.getCityFromFile(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look for [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator. It allows to make the operation in the same thread as the `Observable` (it transforms `Observable`).

```
Subscription subscription = obs
   .subscribeOn(backgroundThread)
   .flatMap(repository::saveCityToDb)
   .observeOn(mainThread)
   .subscribe(city -> view.cityExists());
```

Remember, that the function

`repository::saveCityToDb`

Must return something for the `Observable` to continue. I would suggest it to return the object `Observable.just(city)`.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing correct, but it works if I write .flatMap(repository::saveCityToDb) (not .flatMap(city -> repository::saveCityToDb)) and return not city object from saveCityToDb() but Observable<City>. This is saveCityToDb(): 
public Observable<City> saveCityToDb(City city){
        return Observable.just(city);
    }

Comment: Fixed my answer according to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
Subscription subscription = obs
       .subscribeOn(backgroundThread)
       .doOnNext(city -> view.cityExists())
       .observeOn(mainThread)
       .subscribe(repository::saveCityToDb);
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but according to my logs by using this code, the method saveCityToDb isn't started.

Comment: Is the view.cityExists called? You may want to liberally sprinkle `.doOnNext(dummy -> Log.log(...))` to check that all steps occur in their proper order.

Comment: view.cityExists is called. It seems like it doesn't go further after doOnNext()